# How do I export a chart as a png in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, export

Given a chart (normal column chart of whatever), how do I export that chart and only that chart as a PNG?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't do this directly from Excel; you need to use an external application:

1. Select the chart, and then copy it to the clipboard (Ctrl-C).
2. Open a picture editor that supports saving to PNG.
3. Do a paste in the picture editor (when copying the chart from Excel
   2010, it is recognized as a valid picture on the clipboard). The best will be to paste *as new image* if the picture editor supports that.
4. Save as PNG.

Comment: I think it's most easiest way to do that, there another method to do this is write VB script

Comment: This works for selected cells as well as charts

Comment: Works in itself, but I find the resulting image to be of a lesser quality than the original. Lightshot does not have that problem. That is a very lightweight application that comes with a very easy upload function. See https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working within the Office environment you don't need any other software, all you need to do is select & copy your chart then choose the `Paste Special` option.  One of those paste options is PNG.  The others include:

- PNG
- JPEG
- GIF
- EMF
- BMP
- Microsoft Office Drawing Object

If you need to export outside of the Office environment, then you can use Office Picture Manager.  Just paste your chart inside your My Pictures folder (or whereever is most convenient).  My charts paste as PNG by default, but if yours don't, you can choose your image and `File>Export` and choose your file type, inlcuding PNG, from the list.

Answer (score 2):

There's a free, open-source Excel add-in to accomplish that, "Daniel's XL Toolbox" (https://www.xltoolbox.net).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try VBA:

When on the active chart click <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

and type:

`Activechart.export "D:\chart.png"` (use relevant file location - avoid the system partition)

You can change the file extension as you wish (png, jpeg etc.)

Comment: Alt+F11 gets you to the VBA window, but not to a console / textbox in which you can type.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go via printing/exporting to pdf first as I cannot see how to achieve print quality via the default export methods mentioned above.  Once exported to pdf you can export to the desired image format from there via snipping tool or pdf to png command e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/50170/how-to-convert-pdf-to-image/50180.

Comment: I've used screen capture from PDF and it isn't even near print quality even if the target area in PDF is so small that it can be enlarged 400% (and thus the captured image resolution being over 300dpi in original size). Then again, my printer does 600dpi but the results I got looked way worse than what 300dpi should be (probably due to on-screen image being mangled by anti-aliasing etc). So, I'd very much recommend using some PDF to image tool (many image processing application can import PDF files at given resolution).

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu with Excel 2010 on POL/Wine:

1. Select chart `Home`->`Copy` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>. Note that `Home`->`Copy as Picture` option does not work for me so first try with the standard copy.
2. Open Gimp from the Dash. If you don't have Gimp installed, you can use LibreOffice Draw.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> to paste.
4. For Gimp: use `File`->`Export` and set the file name and format.
5. LibreOffice Draw: Select the pasted image, <kbd>Right-Click</kbd>->`Save Image`

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer from 6½ years ago.

Comment: @Scott - I agree that it is essentially the same, but with added info for those that might be new to doing this in Ubuntu/Gimp/LibreOffice. Most importantly, `Copy as Picture` option works for me in Windows but not in Ubuntu and it took me a while to figure out the issue. Anyway, I'm happy to delete this answer (or feel free to delete it) if it does not add value.