# How to export embedded graphics from Office 2013 (Excel)?

Tags: images, microsoft-office, export, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel document with a lot of small graphics. I'd like to export them, however I've failed to find such option. I'd expect it to appear in right-click menu but it's not there. I've expected it to be found in google, but I've found only suggestion to copy-paste to paint (also [here](https://superuser.com/a/466819/60171)) (I could do printScreen as well) or to write VB Macro.

Does Excel 2013 actually has such simple functionality as saving embedded image[s] to disk? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Pleas have a look [at a similar question](http://superuser.com/q/624445/50173). You may run into the same problem. However, the first you should try is [the extract method](http://superuser.com/questions/624445/how-to-save-duplicate-images-in-excel-to-different-jpegs/624700#comment776893_624447)

Comment: On the file change the .xlxs extension to .zip.  Open up the compressed folder and search for an images folder.  Drag and drop those pictures to export.

Answer (score 0):

The linked question and comments have the answer just adding it here as a proper answer.

Rename the .xlsx file extension to .zip. Then navigate into the compressed folder to the images. Path (in Excel 2013) is 'xl\media'